# React: Is it possible to access a DOM element's props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to react. I've noticed many people binding `this` to their DOM's elements functions.

Let's say I have a component with:

```
render(){
    <div>
        <button onClick={this.doSomething.bind(this)} test={someObj}></button>
    </div>
}

doSomething(){
    this.props.whatever();
}
```

Now, In my mind it made sense having `this` bound to `this.doSomething`, because otherwise `this` would be the button component object, and the this.props would be relative to the button's props, which is something I don't want.

So I got caught in a situation where I wanted to get something from the button's props (the `test` object). What I thought I could do: remove the `bind(this)` from the call, so `this.props` would be the button's props. But when I call `this.doSomething` without using bind, `this` is returning null (maybe I'm messing this up somehow).

I guess my logic is flawed then. I would like to know what's the real purpose of binding `this` to the handlers and if there's a way that I can access a DOM element's props (or at least, how can I get the `test` in the example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store data-value in button as follows:

```
 render(){
<div>
    <button  data-value="item1" onClick={this.doSomething.bind(this)} test={someObj}></button>
</div>
```

}

And access using this:

```
doSomething(event){
console.log(event.target.dataset.value)
this.props.whatever();
}
```

Comment: Are you using ES6?

Comment: pass event as an argument to doSomething(event)

Comment: Yes I am and yes I am passing the event. Dataset is returning me an empty `DOMStringMap {}`

Comment: My bad. I didn't see you saying that it should be a `data-` value. I was trying with test, didn't work, but data-test did. Thank you

Comment: Going to accept yours since you talked about the `data-` before ivarni did but thanks for the help of both

Comment: Thank you but I suggest you use ivarni solution as he gave react solution and I gave javascript solution.

Answer (score 3):

The click handler gets passed a [SyntheticEvent](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html) and you can access the DOM node via that event

```
doSomething(event) {
    console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-test'));
}
```

Alternatively you can give the DOM element a [reference](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

```
<button data-test={someObj} ref="myButton" />
```

and access that as

```
doSomething() {
    console.log(this.refs.myButton)
}
```

But really, you shouldn't use the DOM as a database, and rather store any data for later in your component's state.

EDIT:

For the usecase explained in the comments here I'd do something like this:

```
class MyButton extends React.Component {
    handleClick() {
        this.props.foo(this.props.id);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button 
                    onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
                >
                    Click {this.props.id}
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    foo(id) {
        console.log(id);
    }
    render() {
        const objs = [{id:1},{id:2}];
        return (
            <div>
                {objs.map(obj => (<MyButton key={obj.id} id={obj.id} foo={this.foo}/>))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here we've made a custom component for the button and are keeping our data away from the DOM and in that component's props instead.

Comment: `event.target.getAttribute('test')` is still giving me null.

Comment: Thing is, in my case I have a dynamic generated list, and when it clicks a element I want to get his 'key' or something. So I can't get it by ref since it's dynamic. I guess I could bind the key attribute with `onClick={this.doSomething.bind(null, key)}` but it sounds ugly

Comment: @GBarroso Right.. react might not render it into the dom without the `data-` prefix. It works [here](http://jsbin.com/cotovukapu/1/edit?js,console,output). I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yeah that was it. Now it's working. But for the situation I described do you have some smarter solution? Using `event.target` is a bit meh for me, it's ok but I would like if there was something more beautiful

Comment: What you could do would be to make the elements in the list into a custom component, then pass it its id as a prop and also pass a callback. Inside that component you add an `onClick` handler for the button and in that handler you invoke the callback that was handed down with the id as an argument. That's how I would do it.